# Remove XML node depending on attribute value

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to remove some node from an XML depending on the attribute value using XSL v1.
So far I know how to do that ([XSLT Remove Element Based On Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618294/xslt-remove-element-based-on-attribute))

My problem is that I want to pass some kind of an array/string to the XSL so that I can tell the XSL what node to remove.

Exemple:

XML:

```
<Segments xmlns="http://www.exchangefortravel.org/xft/current" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Segments Name="PrixDispo" What="List">
        <Segment xsi:type="SegmentProductType" Index="1">
            <Code Role="Reference" Value="A"/>
            <Descriptions></Descriptions>
        </Segment>
        <Segment xsi:type="SegmentProductType" Index="2">
            <Code Role="Reference" Value="B"/>
            <Descriptions></Descriptions>
        </Segment>
        <Segment xsi:type="SegmentProductType" Index="3">
            <Code Role="Reference" Value="C"/>
            <Descriptions></Descriptions>
        </Segment>
        <Segment xsi:type="SegmentProductType" Index="4">
            <Code Role="Reference" Value="D"/>
            <Descriptions></Descriptions>
        </Segment>
    </Segments>
 </Segments>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:param name="codes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Segments/Segment/Code[@Value='$code']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And when I call the transformation I'm passing something like "A-D" to the "codes" param.
The result I'm waiting for is:

```
<Segments xmlns="http://www.exchangefortravel.org/xft/current" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Segments Name="PrixDispo" What="List">
        <Segment xsi:type="SegmentProductType" Index="1">
            <Code Role="Reference" Value="A"/>
            <Descriptions></Descriptions>
        </Segment>
        <Segment xsi:type="SegmentProductType" Index="2">
            <Code Role="Reference" Value="D"/>
            <Descriptions></Descriptions>
        </Segment>
    </Segments>
</Segments>
```

My two problems are:

1. What is the best way to pass a list/array/string of values that I can use in the XSL ?
2. How can I use this list to filter my elements ?

Thanks

**EDIT**:
I think I'm approching the solution with that XSL.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:xft="http://www.exchangefortravel.org/xft/current" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="codes"/>

    <xsl:template match="xft:Segment[@xsi:type='SegmentProductType']">
        <xsl:variable name="current_code"  select="xft:Code[@Role='Reference']/@Value"/>
        <xsl:if test="contains($codes, $current_code)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT2**:

Ok so actually what I was trying to do is the oposite, meaning to only keeps 'A' and 'D' node but the problem is the same and when I'll have found how to do I'll adapt the solution to the problem I described here.

I updated my code with the real content I'm dealing with.

Comment: Can you tell how the parameter will be filled (`<xsl:param name="codes"/>`). You say "something like 'A-D'". Can you be specific? And does A-D mean A till D. Or does it mean A and D? What if you pass 4 values, how would it look like?

Comment: @MarkVeenstra
"A-D" is just a list of codes, it is not an interval, it could be "A-D-B".
I pass this value by setting some parameters to my XSL processor when I run the transformation:
`$proc = new XSLTProcessor();`
`$proc->setParameter('', 'codes', 'A-D');`
`$proc->transformToXml($xml_doc);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly did it.
Here is the correct XSL for excluding all elements but those with the allowed Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:xft="http://www.exchangefortravel.org/xft/current" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="codes"/>
    <!-- By Default copy all elements -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- For the Segment elements retreive the coresponding code and look for a match -->
    <xsl:template match="xft:Segment[@xsi:type='SegmentProductType']">
        <xsl:variable name="current_code"  sele    ct="xft:Code[@Role='Reference']/@Value"/>
        <!-- If we have valid code copy the element -->
        <xsl:if test="contains($codes, concat($current_code, '-'))">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Big thanks to @MarkVeenstra

Answer (score 2):

### Getting Values Into XSLT

#### Parameters

You can provide parameters to the XSLTProcessor...

```
$xslt = new XsltProcessor();
$xslt->importStylesheet($xslDom);
$xslt->setParameter('', 'PARAMETER_NAME', 'A D');
```

... that can be defined in XSLT as children of the stylesheet element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="...">
  <xsl:param name="PARAMETER_NAME">default</xsl:param>
  ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### document()

Inside XSLT, the document() function can be used to load additional xml documents. The method does only work with "constant" values. It can not be used inside a loop for example. The good thing is that it is only loaded once in the script run. Even if the template that contains the call is executed multiple times.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="...">
  <xsl:variable name="values" select="document('values.xml')/values"/>
  ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is possible to use PHP Streamwrappers in document(). If you register your own streamwrapper you can call back inside your application.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="...">
  <xsl:variable name="values" select="document('mystream://identifier')/values"/>
  ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### PHP Callbacks

It is possible to call (static) php functions from xslt. The functions can return a DOMDocument, too. Unlike the direct document() call, it is executed each time so it can use a local variable inside a loop.

```
$xslt = new XsltProcessor();
$xslt->importStylesheet($xslDom);
$xslt->registerPHPFunctions(array('callbackFetchingValues'));

<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
  extension-element-prefixes="php">
  <xsl:variable name="values" select="php:function('callbackFetchingValues')/values"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Filtering Nodes

#### Token List

Token lists are strings in XML, that are separated by whitespaces. The most common known is the class attribute in (X)HTML.

```
<div class="tokenOne tokenTwo">...</div>
```

To match against a token list string you have to normalize the string, append spaces to the start and end, resulting in [space][tokenOne][space][tokenTwo][space]. After that you can check for [space][value][space]. In Xpath:

```
segments/segment/code[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space($TOKEN_LIST), ' '), concat(' ', @value, ' '))]
```

#### Node Set

If the values is a node set, you can check against it by selecting from it. You have to put your current value into a variable.

```
<xsl:template match="segments/segment/code">
  <xsl:variable name="current" select="@value"/>
  <xsl:if test="count($filterValues/value[text() = $current]) = 0">
    <!-- not in filter -->
  </xsl>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Awesome I'm gonna try all this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT will do the trick when you pass the parameter correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="codes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="segment">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($codes, code/@value)" /> <!-- Do nothing -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Above XSLT will output only segments that do not match the codes passed into the parameter. If you want to do the opposite (only display codes passed in the parameter), change:

```
<xsl:template match="segment">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($codes, code/@value)" /> <!-- Do nothing -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

To:

```
<xsl:template match="segment">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($codes, code/@value)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi thanks I updated my problem with real case senario, I'm almost there but I can't get anything out of the transformation.
Do you see anything in my last EDIT that is not right ?